# C - How to adapt this code for a very large/dynamic array to a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays

```
 int main()
  {

    double *array;
    long int n;
    n=10000000;//10^7
    array = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    return 0;
  }
```

basically, I want to use this code for a really big aray into a 2 dimensional array, which will have dimensions `[very large][4]`.

Comment: I am not sure on your requirements but I suggest looking at GMP https://gmplib.org/ ( considering your manipulations are mostly in doubles and long ints )

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a 2D array, then allocate a 2D array. It's that simple.

```
double (*pArr)[4] = malloc(10000000 * sizeof pArr[0]);
```

Notes:

- [do not cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).
- use `sizeof pArr[0]` instead of `sizeof(TheDataType)` for defensive programming reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This seems working on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/p7fMoaTUvJ3QD7zM).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    double (* array)[4];
    long int n;
    int i, j;
    n=10000000;//10^7
    array =  (double (*)[4]) malloc(n*sizeof(double[4]));

    printf("%u\n",(unsigned int)sizeof(array[0]));
    printf("%u\n",(unsigned int)sizeof(double[4]));
    for (i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) array[i][j] = (double)i * j;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) printf("%f ", array[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    for (i = n - 10; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) printf("%f ", array[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [do not cast the return value of `malloc()`, it is harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). Use `sizeof ptr[0]` instead of `sizeof(ElementType)` for safety reasons.

Answer (score -1):

```
int n = 100000;
double** array = malloc(sizeof(double*)*n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    array[i] = malloc(4*sizeof(double));
}
```

Also note that we don't cast the malloc's result([Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).

Comment: can i ask why the for loop uses i from 0 to 10?

Comment: This is not a 2D array either, this is a (pointer to the first element of an) array of pointers.

Comment: @ParamagneticCroissant what's a 2D array for you? A true 2D `char bigArray[1000000000][4]` would most likely segfault, any other way of solving the OP's problem?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz He wants `malloc()` so your argument about the auto-allocated array is irrelevant. You can dynamically allocate a true 2D array (which is contiguous in memory), exactly the way I've shown it.